# What ML algorithms would you suggest in fraud detection?

Tags: machine-learning, algorithm

There are a lot of ML algorithms suggested for fraud detection. Now, I have not been able to find a general overview for all of them. My goal is to create this overview. What algorithms would you suggest and why?